# python kubernetes watch crashes

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have been trying to use the python kubernetes API to stream the output of kubernetes logs. I plan to retrieve the logs and ultimately use web Socket to stream logs.

```
from kubernetes import watch
...
def getLog(pod,namespace):
   w = watch.Watch()
   return w.stream(v1.read_namespaced_pod_log, name=pod, namespace=namespace)
```

```
main():
   result = getLog(pod, namespace)
   for line in result:
      print(line)
```

However i get the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./kubernetes-project", line 176, in <module>
    main()
  File "...venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 143, in stream
    yield self.unmarshal_event(line, return_type)
  File "...venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 91, in unmarshal_event
    js['raw_object'] = js['object']
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

The expected output should be below. However, the logs were streaming until `128,`. `3` is the expected output in the next line.

```
...
"random_crop_size": [
   384,
   128, **streaming stops here and error starts showing below**
   3
...
```

I suspect that the error could be due to the line with only `3` is being convert to an `int` object and not string thus `watch` can't process it.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you cut out substantial parts of the error traceback?

Comment: No, i did not, i have only edit the traceback file directory to remove unnecessary information

Comment: @CccAv I wrote a library which makes this easier, if you're interested https://docs.robusta.dev/master/developer-guide/actions/writing-playbooks.html#implementing-your-first-playbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had been tracked & resolved in the latest version of kubernetes. See https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/983 at v11.0.0